# How to execute a service that check the status of backend data at all application use AngularJS

Tags: ajax, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui

Like it's mentionned on the title, I'm trying to create an Angular service that will be used like a listenner on the backend, It will check if the backend finished calculating a list process and return what is not finished yet.
For example: reexecute the verification every 5 seconds while the user is still on the application interface.

Comment: Maybe websocket could be a better idea. It will avoid you to do multiple and useless requests to check if your task is over or not.

Comment: Actually I figured out that $interval allows us to do that

Comment: $interval is only a wrapper that will execute a function every x milliseconds. It indeed will do what you want, but it's probably not the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the difficulty of doing this will be to have your backend report the progress of its calculation, but, assuming you have that figured out, the frontend portion seems like it could be fairly straightforward.

Your service could, e.g., with the [`$http` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http), make repeated requests to some backend controller until the backend returns a sentinel to signify it has completed calculating.

The frontend program flow would be like this:

- Make request to backend
- Wait for response
- When response is successfully received:

  - Update frontend scope/vars/view/whatever with received data
  - If response contains `completed` sentinel, stop making requests
  - If response *doesn't* contain `completed` sentinel, repeat this process (after some delay)

I made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/txyztk2a/1/) with a very simple example of what I mean. Every three seconds it makes another request to the backend (using the [`$timeout` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout)).